# PHP - How to read ANSI escape code CSI 6n

Tags: php, ansi-escape

How can I read the result of ANSI escape code CSI 6n with PHP  ?

(DSR – Device Status Report: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes)

```
<?php
fwrite(STDOUT, "\033[6n");
$code = fread(STDIN,1);
die($code);
```

This code will execute CSI 6n, but I am not able to capture the response, it will always be printed out when php exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make some provision for reading unbuffered input.  Here is an example:

```
<?php
$term = trim(`stty -g`);
system("stty -icanon -echo");
fwrite(STDOUT, "\033[6n");
$code = trim (fread(STDIN,100) );
system("stty '" . $term . "'");
if ( sscanf($code, "\033[%d;%dR", $row, $col) == 2 ) {
    printf ("position %d,%d\n", $row, $col );
} elseif ( strlen ($code ) > 0 ) {
    printf ("unexpected %d-byte reply\n", strlen ($code ));
}
?>
```